# Put divs previously under "float atribute" go down

Tags: css, html, css-float

Let's say i have a section with three divs side by side and the main div (center) occupies 50% of the space, 25% for the ones in the left and the right.

Now, i'm using media queries to display the site in best conditions on kindle portrait (600 x 1024).

Since it's a lower resolution, to make the site look better i thought in puttin the main column appear and in tho bottom of her put the two that was previously at side.

I was able with "float" atribute to put the main div on the left, but it happens that the other two don't go under the main one.

Is that even possible to do? I'm trying but i'm far far away of being able to do what i pretend.

Html code:

```
<section id="content">
<div class="main_1">
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="main_2">
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="main_3">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
   #content{
    border:0;
    padding:15px 5px 15px 55px;
    margin:0;
    min-height:600px;
    border:1px solid;
    overflow:visible;
    box-shadow:3px 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    overflow:hidden;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:1;
}

.main_1,.main_2,.main_3{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right:1%;
    padding:9px 0;
    min-height:10px;
}

.main_1{width:23.0%;}
.main_2{width:45.0%;}
.main_3{width:22.0%;}
```

The previous code was for high resolutions. Now for the kindle (600x1024) i used the follow to put the main div at right but the other ones are a mess on the left:

CSS:

```
.main_1,.main_3{
        display:inline;
        float:right;
        margin-left:1%;
        margin-right:1%;
        padding:9px 0;
        min-height:10px;
    }

    #content .main_2{
    float: left;

}
```

SOLVED:

I don't know if it was the best idea in terms of code, but i duplicate my div of the left and put it hidden beetwen div center and right.

In media queries i just had to hide the div of the left and "activate" the one i had hide that was equal but now on the right side of the center div.

Comment: you have your html and css for this example handy?

Comment: yes, i edited the post above and put the code there.

Comment: How i do that? Click on the upper arrow?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you always set the wider content first, and the last two in sequence and just that change will help you and will probably solve your problem, because when you don't have enough room for the smaller ones, they will fall under the first content box. Do you get it?

Doing this, you can float the wider element to the left and the other two to the right. Just don't forget that floating the other two elements to the right will invert their order, so you'll have to work your html a little.

Comment: But for that i can't use % on the widths of the divs right?

What your saying is to float left the main div with, let's supose 300px and set the content widht with 320. If the other divs, floated left, go with 100px each they will go down. Is that it? I understood well?

Comment: In your last media query you have 600px wide, right? If you're floating your elements, you could set the width of one of them to something like 98% and the other two to something like 48%. But in this case, the first element must be the wider. That's why I'm telling you to work your html in a better way so the first element is always the bigger/wider/main one.

Comment: I see your point, but my problem is precisely that one. I can't modify the html because i want to mantain the order of the divs like they are because of the higher resolutions when the three appear side by side.

Comment: You could achieve the same "effect" on the higher resolutions changing the html the way I told you, but that's ok. In your last media query, from 600px and below, your layout will still be flexible?

Comment: But if i understood right, the way you said i would have to change place divs in the html or at least change the size of them there correct?

Be flexible? Hmm, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Actually, I don't know what content you'll have in your html so I don't know if what I'm thinking for the wider view would work. By "flexible" I mean: you're smallest media query size is 600px? Meaning that the layout won't adapt if the browser is 500px wide, 400px wide and so on... because if 600px will be your min-width, so there's no point in using % anymore and you can start working with other solutions like fixed widths with css positioning.

Comment: I pretend to create other media queries for smaller devices. I just thought for this one would look good make the center div appear alone and the other two below her since to show the three or two of them side by side doesn't look good with 600px width.

Comment: I don't know what you're thinking for the smaller widths (below 600px) but maybe you could start working with a fixed with layout below 600px.

Comment: I didn't think yet xD Now i'm trying to fix this, one step at time :P

Comment: Hope someone will be able to help you but I can't think of anything that would work for you now... when working with media queries, it's a good practice to think all your different layouts before starting to work/code.